# How to get and post contracts details using the Azure Blockchain Workbench REST API

Tags: azure-blockchain-workbench

I have followed the steps of creating a helloblockchain workbench application for request and responder type.I have got the all contracts details using Azure Blockchain Workbench REST API using "/api/v1/contracts/{{contractId}}".But i unable to post the message or actions using the api "api/v1/contracts/{{contractid}}/actions".So please some one help me regarding this.

Comment: Can you be more specific what is not working? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create a new contract, you need to use the constructor as the function ID.

And the API that you are using"api/v1/contracts/{{contractid}}/actions" is for creating a response to an already existing contract and it can only be performed by passing the credentials of a Responder in the Authentication bearer.